# GSON identifying JSON Object as Primitive

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am writing a relatively simple messaging app that saves its logs in the JSON format, and I am using the GSON library to parse these. I load a JSON file from a server, and put it trough `Gson.toJsonTree()` function. I'm not sure this is expected, but when I test the result from the previous function with the `isJsonSomething()` functions (`isJsonObject`,`isJsonAray`,`isJsonNull`,`isJsonPrimitive`), `isJsonPrimitive` returns true, and I can't parse it into a object. This is my JSON file's contents:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "picture": "", 
            "type": "user", 
            "name": "kroltan"
        }
    ], 
    "description": "No description", 
    "messages": [

        {
            "content": "something", 
            "time": "2013-08-30 00:38:17.212000", 
            "type": "message", 
            "author": "someone"
        }
    ], 
    "type": "channel", 
    "name": "default"
}
```

And here is the class used to parse it into POJOs: (CLEANUP comments is where I've removed irrelevant code from the post)

```
package com.example.testapp;

//CLEANUP: All needed imports

import com.example.testapp.data.*;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class JSONConverter {
    public interface JsonTypeLoadedListener {
        public void onSucess(JSONType jsonType);
        public void onFailure(Exception e);
    }
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS";
    public static final HashMap<String, Class<?>> JSON_TYPES = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    public JSONConverter() {
        JSON_TYPES.clear();
        JSON_TYPES.put("channel", Channel.class);
        JSON_TYPES.put("user", User.class);
        JSON_TYPES.put("message", Message.class);
    }
    public void loadFromURL(final URL url, final JsonTypeLoadedListener listener) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JsonObject result = null;
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).create();
                if (url.getProtocol().equals("http")) {
                    try {
                        String content = //Loads from a server, omitted for clarity
                        result = gson.toJsonTree(content).getAsJsonObject();
                        conn.disconnect();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        listener.onFailure(e);
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (url.getProtocol().equals("file")) {
                    try {
                        String content = //Loads from a file, omitted for clarity
                        result = gson.toJsonTree(content).getAsJsonObject();
                        br.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        listener.onFailure(e);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                listener.onSucess((JSONType) gson.fromJson(result, JSON_TYPES.get(result.get("type").getAsString())));
            }

        }, "URLLoader").start();
    }
    public JSONType loadFromString(String s) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject result = gson.toJsonTree(s).getAsJsonObject();
        return (JSONType) gson.fromJson(result, JSON_TYPES.get(result.get("type").getAsString()));
    }
}
```

The classes `Message`, `User` and `Channel` all inherit from JSONType (a custom class with a field called type and some utility methods) and contain all values present in the above mentioned JSON file.

When it reaches `gson.toJsonTree(content).getAsJsonObject()`, I get this error in Logcat (string omitted for clarity, it's just the full file):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "String containing all the file with tabs represented as \t"
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that `content` (not `contents`) is declared, and I doubt your example code will compile.

Comment: As mentioned, I removed some parts of code for readability. content is defined correctly in the network load code and the file read code, which were omitted. I`ll make this clearer in a sec

Comment: I should also note this JSON file is valid, as per <jsonlint.com>

Comment: Have you actually debugged this and manually inspected the contents of `contents` before you call `toJsonTree`? That error really sounds like you're somehow feeding it the wrong input.

Comment: @chrylis Yeah, I did. It just shows the whole JSON contents, with tabls represented as `\t` and quotes inside it escaped as `\"`

Comment: ...so when you wrote `"String containing all the file..."`, that wasn't the actual error message, you were just being cute?

Comment: As expressed just above the exception. True error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "{\t\"users\": [\t\t{\t\t\t\"picture\": \"\", \t\t\t\"type\": \"user\", \t\t\t\"name\": \"kroltan\"\t\t}\t], \t\"description\": \"No description\", \t\"messages\": [\t\t\t\t{\t\t\t\"content\": \"something\", \t\t\t\"time\": \"2013-08-30 00:38:17.212000\", \t\t\t\"type\": \"message\", \t\t\t\"author\": \"someone\"\t\t}\t], \t\"type\": \"channel\", \t\"name\": \"default\"}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the tabs are causing your issue. Try to remove them with:

```
content = content.replaceAll("\\s","")
```

this will simply clean your json string from any whitespace.

Btw I suggests you to get rid of Gson library and use directly the JSONObject provided in the android sdk. You can initialize it directly with the json string, as `new JSONObject(content)`. :)

Comment: I still get the exact same error, with all tabs still existing.

Comment: Ah, used the function from before your edit, it doesn`t parse regexes, apparently

Comment: Now I have the problem that quotes are also escaped. Tried using `.replaceAll("\\\"","\"")`, but it doesn`t change anything.

Comment: What do you mean? That function should remove only the spaces. Could you post your JSON before the replaceAll and the after? :)

Comment: Oh nevermind, I wrote the replaceAlls on the file protocol, silly me. I beleive it's working now

Comment: Or maybe not... I`m not able to replace those pesky escaped quotes with plain quotes!

Comment: had to change the function to remove ALL backslashes from the JSON, but it worked now.

Comment: Cool. Btw if that's the case I would investigate on how you get the json! Probably you're reading it not correctly (are you reading it from a file?). :)

Comment: I'm reading it from a web server as plain text and when i Log it it displays fine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36729/discussion-between-enrichman-and-kroltan)