# Check if a jsonobject is nested ot not?

Tags: java, json, recursion

I have 2 jsons like `{"a1":{"b1":{"c1":"value1"},"b2":{"c2":{"d2":"value2"}}}}` and `{"a1":{"b2":{"c2":{"d2":"value2"}},"b1":{"c1":"value1"}}}`.
I am trying to write a method that compares the 2 jsons.
I have a recursive function, but I don't know how to check whether a json object is nested with other json objects or not (this is required for putting an end criteria in recursion)

Here's my code so far:

```
 public static boolean verifyResponse(JSONObject json1,JSONObject json2)
    {
        Object keyarray[]=json1.keySet().toArray();
        int i=0;
        while(i<keyarray.length)
        {
            if(!verifyResponse((JSONObject)json1.get(keyarray[i].toString()),(JSONObject)json2.get(keyarray[i].toString())))
            {
                return false;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Related, overlapping and possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118708/determine-whether-json-is-a-jsonobject-or-jsonarray

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592762/gson-identifying-json-object-as-primitive

Comment: Here I don't know the key names as well.

Comment: You have three cases here, simple value, object {} and array [], where the array can contain any of the three cases as an item. You could trim the surrounding whitespace, then check the first and last characters.